# run shell command (manage-bde) as administrator from C#

Tags: c#, .net, shell

I need to run "manage-bde" shell command from C# code.

The main application process is already running as administrator and is Elevated.

I used code from : UAC self-elevation example on MS website for confirming the app process is elevated. 
(http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSUACSelfElevation-644673d3)

However, when I try to run manage-bde from the C# code, I get "System can't find file specified".

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\manage-bde.exe";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        p.Start();
```

As a workaround, I tried to create a batch file that runs the command.

```
        string batchFileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".bat";
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(batchFileName);
        writer.WriteLine("manage-bde");
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();               
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = batchFileName;               
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;                             
        p.Start();
```

The batch file is written , and executed successfully; However, the command "manage-bde" is not recognized.

I changed the code to use the verb "runas" and use admin password and that works, but I want the batch file to work without the need for providing the admin password. The current logged in user is already administrator on the computer but the batch file is not getting executed with the existing admin privileges . I need the batch file to execute and manage-bde to run successfully.

Your help or advice will be very highly appreciated :)

ps: some commands other than manage-bde work fine without need for admin runas.

Comment: `I used code from : UAC self-elevation example on MS website for confirming the app process is elevated`, if that's the case there is significant code involved with that, including calls to Native Windows API. Did you fully implement the solution? It's also using the Windows Identity Framework. Again, did you ***fully*** implement the solution in that example?

Comment: I added NativeMethods.cs and copied the relevant function "IsElevated" from that example  ; the function returns true . i used that just to confirm that my process is at elevated level when running the batch file process

Comment: calling "RunAs" with username  and password causes process.start to call the native method (CreateProcessWithLogonW). This creates a new security context and runs the application (manage-bde in this case) from it. This new security context is a 64 bits context that is not redirected when it access system32.
If I do not use a username and password, the native method called will be: (CreateProcess). This starts the new process in the same security context of the calling app (which is a 32 bits context in my case above). As a result the access is redirected to syswow64 and the file is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the behavior I encountered was the Windows File System Redirector.

> In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

My application build was 32 bits. Whenever it tried to access System32 windows automatically redirected it to SysWow64 which does not contain "manage-bde.exe".  I changed the build to 64 bits and then the application could access manage-bde.exe from System32

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're running as the Administrator user, you're not fully elevated if UAC is running. Meaning that you'll have either the UAC prompt come up or you'll be prompted for a password.

The only real way you could get around that is to run your application elevated first, or to write a service that runs with elevated permissions to start your new process.

The alternative of course is to disable UAC, but that is undesirable in most situations.

Comment: The OP specifically stated `but I want the batch file to work without the need for providing the admin password` making this solution completely invalid.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud didn't notice that, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @PhonicUK thanks for your response . The point at which I start the process (Process.Start())  , my calling process is elevated. I confirmed that by calling IsElevated from the code mentioned above . It only runs successfully if I provide runas verb , and enter an admin username and password with the process startInfo